# evaluating $ \sqrt {2+ \sqrt {3+ \sqrt{4+ \sqrt{5+\cdots}}} }$

Tags: nested-radicals

How do we evaluate the infinite nested radical  $  \sqrt {2+ \sqrt {3+ \sqrt{4+ \sqrt{5+\cdots}}} } $ $\space $?

Please help

N.B. :- It is not a duplicate

Comment: Your edit has made a big change in the problem. Are you sure you have it right now?

Answer (score 9):

There is no known closed form for this number, except $C^2-1$, where $C=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\dots}}}$ is the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html). By a numerical evaluation, I find

$$C^2-1=2.090327576790576359192544506688116904296\dots$$